# Typescript , get a specific property of response data

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rxjs

Below is my response data format.

In Typescript :  how to get the 1st item's "_Name" value which is inside the "ResultList" array of the response data ?

Using **this.responseData$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));**
I am able to see the response data in browser

```
ResultList: Array(1)
0: {
_CodeID: "112344", 
_Name: "ABCGDJFJFJF", // Want to get this property value
 _IsADV: false
}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
_Acknowledge: 2
_Bild: "5256"
_CId: "641645DF-E5E5-481A-B8E7-94FE2DRFFFFF"
_MachineName: "*******"
_Message: ""
_ReservationExpires: ""
_RId: ""
_RowsAffected: 0
_Version: "1.0"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get it"?

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax, so I want to get the the value of the  1st item's "_Name" property, which is inside the "ResultList" array of the response data

Comment: If the `val` is `ResultList`, so val[0]._Name ?

Comment: val has resultList and other data also, not only ResultList

Comment: Well in that case `val.ResultList[0]._Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context how you later plan to use this variable, but one option is to just extract it in the subscribe block:

```
this.responseData$.subscribe(val => {
  const whatIsNeeded = val.ResultList[0]._Name;
  // do somehting with variable whatIsNeeded
});
```

Other one is to pipe it to another observable.

```
const whatIsNeededObservable: Observable<string> = this.responseData$.pipe(map(val => val.ResultList[0]._Name));
```

More info about piping and mapping can be found here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map